# Select JSON records as an Excel table

Tags: arcgis-server, excel, table, json, map-service

I have an internal map service that serves up GIS records via **JSON objects**.

> For the purpose of this question, instead of using my internal/private
> data, we can use the JSON data on ESRI's **public** Sample Server 6.
>
> - https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Events/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&f=pjson

---

Question:

I want to select the JSON data and insert it into an Excel [table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c).

In other words, I want to take the JSON data:

[image]

And put it into a tab in an Excel spreadsheet as rows:

[image]

How can this be done in Excel 2016?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1min job using OGR/GDAL command line. I've changed `f=pjson` to `f=json` in your url. You will just need to open the CSV.

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV localgovernment_events.csv "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Events/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&f=json" -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
```

For points, you may prefer an output with X and Y columns instead of WKT

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV localgovernment_events.csv "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Events/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&f=json" -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY
```

You can also use QGIS by using `f=geojson` like below. It will load as a layer. Then, you will right click on the layer "Export" -> "Save Features As...", choose to export to CSV format or Excel or OpenDocument (LibreOffice format). Be aware that output format does not always keep geometry in the output file.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I can use Excel Power Query.

The steps are pretty unintuitive, so I'll spell them out for future reference:

1. `Excel 2016` >> `Data tab` >> `From Other Sources` >> `From Web`
2. Paste the URL
3. Click `Edit`
4. Remove the `Changed Type` step
5. In the `Source` step's settings, change `Open file as` from CSV to Json
6. Click the `features` row
7. Click `Into Table`
8. Click the `List` hyperlink in the `features` row
9. Click `To Table`
10. Click `Ok`
11. In the header for `Column1`, click the arrows icon:
    [image]
12. Unselect `geometry`, if applicable.
13. Click `Ok`
14. In the header of `Column1.attributes`, click the arrows icon:
    [image]
15. Unselect `Use original column name as prefix`, if applicable.
16. Click `Ok`
17. Change/correct the data types for the columns. *Note: I couldn't figure out how to display the dates correctly.*
18. This is what the resulting data/table looks like in the Power Query window:
    [image]
19. Click `Close & Load`
20. This is what the resulting table in the Excel spreadsheet looks like.
    [image]
21. The query can be refreshed anytime: `Data` tab >> `Refresh All`.
22. Additionally, the refresh settings can be set so that the query refreshes when the spreadsheet file is opened.

*For more details, see the answers in this post: [Select JSON records as Excel table via Power Query](https://superuser.com/questions/1568937/select-json-records-as-excel-table-via-power-query)*